# Modifying Replicated Database Using Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, replication

We have a system that uses replication to allow folks in two different locations to work with a common database back end. The network is not high quality, and slow so I used replication to put a back end at each location and keep them synchronized. Synchronization is done through the Replication Manager and synchronizer running on a schedule. This has been working great for the past two years. The system was originally developed and used with Access 2007 but with the back end in mdb format. So now the client is up to Access 2010. The client wanted some changes to the back end, entailing some new tables and new fields added to existing tables. No problem I think. I went to the site and opened the Replica set design master using Access 2010 and added the new tables with no problem. Then I tried to add the new fields to existing tables. I could do that in design view but when I tried to save the changes I get a message 'Operation not supported for this type of object' message. I banged my head against the wall for a while thinking I was doing something wrong, then gave up working at the client facility. I did run the synchronizer before leaving and the new tables propagated properly to the other managed databases. This part is working.

After returning to my office I thought possibly this is an Access 2010 issue. I fired up a virtual machine with Access 2007 on it and a running replication system of the same database. In Access 2007 I could open the design master and add fields to existing tables with no errors and the changes would save. Is this an Access 2010 issue or is there something else going on? I'd hate to have to re-install Access 2007 on one of the client computers to make these changes. I have the same system running on my Access 2010 machine and I can duplicate the 'Operation not supported for this type of object'  issue using Access 2010 in my office. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The tools are still there if you are working with an mdb format database file. Replication is under the Tools ribbon. I think they want you to roll you own conflict resolution system now. There may be tools on Micheal Kaplans old site.

Comment: If you can recreate the problem under Access 2010 (fully patched) then that's a pretty good indicator that whatever has broken your app is likely to stay broken. Jet replication is **seriously** deprecated (and totally gone from Access 2013, I believe) so you may just have to limp along with Access 2007 until you update the application to use something *other* than Jet replication.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but I have also run into the same problems. I found that using Access DDL (e.g. ALTER TABLE) in the SQL window works to modify table design in a replicated database in Access 2010. It won't allow you to modify an existing field/column but you can at least add or drop fields from existing tables. You can use DDL to modify an existing field by adding a new temporary field to your table the way you want it, copy the data from the existing field to your temporary field, then drop the existing field. Then add a second new field with the name of the field you deleted and copy the data over from the temporary field.  Then delete the temporary field.  More Access DDL info [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/180841/how-to-use-common-data-definition-language-ddl-sql-statements-for-the)